# App Request with JSON to PHP

Tags: php, android, json, .htaccess

As part of a project I am attempting to create my own web portal for an existing, open source android application.

When a user fills out the registration form on the app and hits submit the following happens (pulled from Android Studio via debug):

```
02-25 17:16:18.198  21581-21604/com.zeus I/ZEUS? Sending using 'POST' - URI: http://WEBSITE.com/api/v2/signup.json - parameters: {password_confirmation=SuperSecret12, password=SuperSecret12, email=test@gmail.com, country_name=United Kingdom, name=TestAccount01}
```

I know the app is outputting correctly as it works fine when I point it at its original server.

On the server I am trying to get this to work on I have a .htaccess file with the following in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/v2/signup.json$ api/v2/registeraction.php
```

This redirects the incoming POST to the registeraction.php file, which I want to pull the POST parameters from the request and plug them into the DB. My registeraction.php file looks like this:

```
// (1) Use include to database connection and select database    
$link = mysqli_connect("WEBSITE.mysql","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DB") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

// (2) gather all details from form e.g. $newFirstname = $_POST['txtGiven']
$newUsername = $_POST['name'];
$newEmail = $_POST['email'];
$newPassword = $_POST['password'];
$newCountry = $_POST['country'];


// (3) Create an INSERT query of the form $query
$insert_row = $link->query("INSERT INTO zeususers (username, password) VALUES ('$newUsername', '$newPassword')");

// (4) Where to send the user on completion
if ($link->query($insert_row)) {
        header ('Location: register-thanks.php');
    } else {
        header ('Location: register-thanks.php#');
    }
```

In debugging I am getting the following error after submitting the form:

```
03-05 16:41:30.338    1873-1905/com.zeus I/ZEUS﹕ [0]post:http://WEBSITE.com/api/v2/signup.json{302}
```

I know 302 is URL redirection but nothing else seems to appear after that, it just hangs on that line until the user cancels. However when it is pointed at its original server it comes back with 201 (Created).

Can anyone see why this might not be working? Can provide more details if that helps at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header ('Location: register-thanks.php');
```

this line of code give a HTTP 302 request, which means client should redirect to register-thanks.php

Although you can parse 302 response and follow the guided uri, I suggest using json format as guideline, not HTTP 302. And parse json for guiding user operations.

**Example:**

```
if ($link->query($insert_row)) {
    echo json_encode(array("error_code":0, "error_desc" : "",  "next_uri": "register-thanks.php"));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("error_code":-1, "error_desc" : "USER REG FAILED",  "next_uri": "register-failed.php"));
}
```

You can decide which page should go by checking http 200 with json result.